# best way to write short version of repeatable words in regex | python

Tags: python, regex

I want regex for `a|b|c` repeated many times, separated by space, but regex should not accept tail space:

```
 "a b c c b"  - ok
 "a b c c b " - not ok
```

so I have `"(a|b|c)( (a|b|c))+"` instead of `"((a|b|c) )+"`
but my regex have much more than 3 words, so the pattern is long and unreadable.

```
"^((?:word1|word2|word3|word4|...)(?: (?:word1|word2|word3|word4|...))+)$"
```

I just want ask about short version, using lookahead/lookbehing mechanism for last space or sth similar to match only inner spaces.
     how change `((a|b|c) )+` to achieve that?

Comment: Will anything else follow that space that is not in the set `a|b|c`?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? From what you have written it looks like you're trying to check if all words are from the list and there is no trailing space-maybe it would be better to separate words into list (like PHP's explode), check if every word from list is acceptable + extra-check for the trailing space in the original string?

Comment: Why don't you use string formatting? `"({words})( ({words}))+".format('|'.join(map(re.escape, the_words)))`

Comment: Questioners who don't answer to questions concerning their posts are toilsome.

Comment: I dont need string formatting, re-thinking what I really want and so on - I exactly know what I want - it's the regex, as described in post. indeed is a one of two parts of regex, but I simplify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those are all alphanumeric words, then you can make use of [word boundary anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
^(?:(?:word1|word2|word3|word4|...)\b\s*)+\b$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^      # Start of string
(?:    # Start of non-capturing group, first matching...
 (?:word1|word2|word3|word4|...) # ...one of these words,
 \b    # then matching the end of a word,
 \s*   # then matching zero or more whitespace
)+     # one or more times.
\b     # At the end, make sure that the end of the last word...
$      # ...is at the end of the string.
```

The first `\b` ensures that between words, `\s*` must match at least one whitespace character.

Comment: in python it will be r'^(?:(?:word1|word2|word3|word4|...)\b\s*)+\b$
- wrapped with r'' to handle \b and works with **unicode** - re.match(r'^(?:(?:word1|żółć)\b\s*)+\b$', 'word1 żółć')

Comment: Nice, I have not encountered `\b` yet. According to the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), *"Inside a character range, \b represents the backspace character, for compatibility with Python’s string literals."*

Comment: @ojdo: Yes, but we're outside a character range, and there it means "word boundary".

Comment: @Tim: Yes, no misunderstanding here. I just browsed for the docs and added my finding on the *additional* meaning in another context, in case anyone wonders (like me).

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 similar places in the pattern `(?:word1|word2|word3|word4|...)`. The second one starts with space. You can combine them by having `(?:word1|word2|word3|word4|...)` start with either space or `^`. This  will avoid duplication.

```
>>> compiled = re.compile(r'(?:(?:\s|^)(?:a|b|c))+$')
>>> compiled.match('a b c c b').group(0)
'a b c c b'
>>> compiled.match('a b c c b ')
None
>>> compiled.match('a').group(0)
'a'
>>> compiled.match('a ')
None
```

Comment: it's almost great, because "   word1 word2" (string with many spaces at the beggining) also matched.